# CXF 2.7.3 give error with spring 3.2.1.RELEASE possible conflict with libraries

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, cxf, tomcat6

I have a project prev working fine with Spring 3.0.1 and apache CXF 2.4, but as there were memory leak issues in apache CXF 2.4 I have upgrade to version apache CXF 2.7.3 but it is not working with either spring 3.0.1 nor latest spring version Spring version 3.2.1.  Exception is provided below. I am using maven and provided depedencies in pom.xml

```
 Feb 27, 2013 11:16:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet CXFServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: from stacktrace it is clear by any how XmlWebApplicationCentext class is not reachable. I guess jar is not in class path.

Comment: @Real I have mentioned that i had dependencies with Spring 3.0.1 and 3.2.1 Release version but it is I think not compatible with apache XCF 2.7.3 version. I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok. I guess the problem is not with compatibility, the problem is of missing class in classpath.

Comment: @Real thanks you were right now in apache cxf 2.7.3 spring web is not part of bundle so we have to add its dependency explicitly. Thanks I resolved problem. 10 up from my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Real** comments ***"from stacktrace it is clear by any how XmlWebApplicationCentext class is not reachable. I guess jar is not in class path"*** helped me and I solved the problem by adding spring-web dependency.

Comment: Just an additional note on 'adding spring-web' dependency for other readers: it is the 'org.springframework:spring-web:<version>' dependency you need.

Answer (score 0):

Adding spring-web to dependencies didn't work for me. As a workaround I downgraded to CXF 2.5.0